# Proving that an analytic function is $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given an analytic function $f(z)$ in the region $\Omega=\{z : b>Re(z)>a\}$. It is also given that the function is continuous and bounded in $\overline\Omega$. The question is to show that if $$M(a)=sup\{|f(z)|:Re(z)=a\}=0$$
Then $f(z)$ is zero. I was actually trying to prove the Hadamard's three line theorem. In that I assumed that $M(a)$ and $M(b)$ are non zero and followed the steps as in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-lines_theorem). Now I am struck whenever it is zero. It would be great if anyone can give any hints as to how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it say there, that the [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) should be used for this? Seems to fit.

Comment: @knedlsepp But the maximum modulus principle asks for it to be zero on the boundary but $M(b)$ need not be zero. So how can we conclude?

Comment: Do you know Schwarz' reflection?

Comment: @mrf yes I have heard about it in the context of extending an holomorphic function but I am not sure about how to use that in proving this.

Comment: In the Rudins' book it indicates that the inequality $M(x)^{b-a}\leq M(a)^{b-x}M(b)^{x-a},$ $\forall x\in (a,b)$ can be proven for this case, and then your assertion will be a direct consequence of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get slightly simpler notation, I'll work with $\Omega = \{ z : 0 < \operatorname{Im} z < b \}$ instead. (Translate and rotate your domain to get there.)

Define a new function
$$
g(z) = \begin{cases} 
f(z), & 0 < \operatorname{Im} z < b \\[6pt]
\overline{f(\bar z)}, & -b < \operatorname{Im} z < 0
\end{cases}
$$
From your assumptions on $f$, you can check that $g$ will be holomorphic on $-b < \operatorname{Im} z < b$. And since $g = 0$ on the real axis, the identity principle forces $g$ to vanish everywhere.

Comment: thanks a lot never used reflection principle like you did awesome proof.